# MSVC 14 STL vector reserve

Tags: c++, stl

I have noticed strange behavior (IMO) on MSVC 14 Comm. in Debug x86 solution.
Code below throws Exception when vector::resize is not included.
Note: after assigment some entities may be unassigned by passing nullptr.

```
vector<Entity*> m_entities;

(...)

// find empty slot
u_int id = m_entities.size();
for(u_int i=0; i<m_entities.size(); ++i)
{
    if(m_entities[i] == nullptr)
    {
        id = i;
        break;
    }
}

// vector realloc
if(id == m_entities.capacity())
{
    u_int newSize = m_entities.capacity() * 2;
    m_entities.reserve(newSize);
    //m_entities.resize(newSize);
}

// assign
entity->m_id = id;
m_entities[id] = entity;
```

[image: exception]
[image: debug]

It looks like operator[] checks size() instead of capacity() - am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can NOT access the reserved area of the `vector` if it was not initialized. `reserve` does not initialize anything it just reserve (as it was named) some memory to not `reallocate` the `vector` each time a new item is `pushed back`

Try to run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
class my_class{
    public:
    my_class(){
        x="I am an initialized item";
    }
    std::string x;
};
int main()
{
    std::vector<my_class> v(2);
    v.reserve(3);
    std::cout << v[0].x <<std::endl<< v[1].x <<std::endl <<v[2].x;
}
```

You may got compiling error in the debug mode(depending on your compiler), it may pass and give undefined behaviour (*NOT sure about undefined behaviour please someone edit this part*). In best case, it would run with printing empty string for `v[2]`.

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/9tbt)

Comment: Yeah, I know how reserve works, but if vector reallocate memory so why I cant access it by [] operator which is referenced.

Comment: @juanchopanza is there something wrong with my answer ?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/
"If n is greater than the current vector capacity, the function causes the container to reallocate its storage increasing its capacity to n (or greater)."
IMO from now on new indicies should be accessible.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi No, I was replying to Luk's assertion that he knows how reserve works.

Comment: @Luk No. `[]` only works within the vector's *size*, not within its *capacity.* Capacity is just prepared inaccessible space into which the vector can grow when its size increases, so that it doesn't need to reallocate. But the "buffer" between capacity and size is **not** part of the vector contents and cannot be accessed as such.

Comment: Excellent example. Now I see some usable consequence of this implementation.